# unable to match a Path object to a String pattern

Tags: java, path

I'm new to Java and is trying to learn the class PathMatcher. I have came up with the code below. The file xanadu.txt exist. However, when I run the code, the IDE output "no it doesn't match". Why is this happening?

```
import java.nio.file.FileSystems;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.PathMatcher;
import java.nio.file.Paths;


public class Random {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String pattern = "glob:*.txt";
        PathMatcher matcher = FileSystems.getDefault().getPathMatcher(pattern);

        Path file = Paths.get("/Users/justin/Desktop/Codes Netbean/JavaRandom/xanadu200.txt");

        if(matcher.matches(file)){
            System.out.println("yes it matches");
        } else {
            System.out.println("no it doesnt match");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the problem that you're running into is that the pattern

```
String pattern = "glob:*.txt";
```

isnt taking the rest of the path into consideration try changing it into

```
String pattern = "glob:**/*.txt";
```